# Не получается найти css элемент по cssSelector'у

Tags: c#, selenium, css-selectors

Необходимо выделить из **css** элемента данные , построить из них список . 
подопытный :

первый скрин . 
`с#+selenium webdriver chrome`
скриншоты:

2- видеоурок .код в видеоуроке

3- мой код .

4-результат из видеоурока

5-мой результат

Что я делаю не так? Мужик с видео так же ищет **css** по Id , я делаю так же, только у него выходит , а мне visual studio кажет что я тварь дрожащая .
примечания :
Мужик использует visual studio , если важно это. У меня 2019.
извините если где то тупо и нескладно, я в первый раз. [image: подопытный]
[image: код мужика из урока]
[image: мой код]
[image: результат мужика (все нормально)]
[image: мой результат (все плохо,элемент не находится по Id)]

Comment: Мне кажется тут стоит сразу задать вопрос - почему селениум?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы пропустили `#`.
Надо вот так:
`By.CssSelector("#news_panel_news a")`

Comment: Son
там решетка есть , я просто когда порядок для скрина наводил удалил ее случайно . 
спасибо большое все равно . 
вопрос решился сам собой , перезапустил студио и все стало норм . еще раз спасибо  .

Comment: @Suvitruf - Andrei Apanasik♦
спасибо , все решилось само собой перезапуском студии .

Comment: @Витек мне то за что? Я просто немного сообщение подправил)

Comment: @Suvitruf - Andrei Apanasik♦ все равно спасибо . честно , не ожидал нормального ответа и адекватности . хотя как и сказал , просто лагал студио сам .